# how to set if else condition in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I would like to set if else condition that if user profile is exits execute

```html
<img src="data:image/<%=user.profile.contentType%>;base64, <%=user.profile.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="">
```

else print the following

```html
<img src="css/image/user.svg" alt="">
```

actually user sign into website so there is any image into DB after sign up user will update the image, so I am rendering user data in an EJS file.
Below is my latest attempt.

```html
<% if (user.profile.length > 0) { %>
    <img src="css/image/user.svg" alt=""> <!-- random image -->
<% } else { %>
    <img src="data:image/<%=user.profile.contentType%>;base64,
    <%=user.profile.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="">   <!-- user profile , it will set when user update image -->
<% }  %>
```

but is going to false here is the error:

```
TypeError: C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\views\user.ejs:19
17|      <% } else { %>

18|       <img src="data:image/<%=user.profile.contentType%>;base64,

19|       <%=user.profile.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="">

20|      <% }  %>
```

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
> at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), :34:43)
> at user (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
> at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
> at View.render (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
> at Function.render (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
> at C:\Users\SBCS\Desktop\blog4u\blogs-4u\app.js:237:13
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

below is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String ,
    email:String,
    password:String,
    profile:{ data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});
```

here that i am rendering

```js
app.get('/user', async (req,res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const user = req.user;
        const posts = await Post.find({ user: user._id });

        res.render("user",{ user, posts, message: req.flash('message') });
    } else {
        req.flash('message', "Log in here for user profile");
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you are using to render the page to give you an accurate response?

Comment: here is code which is am render app.get('/user', async (req,res)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        const user = req.user;
        
        const posts = await Post.find({user:user._id})
        
        res.render("user",{user: user ,posts:posts , message :req.flash('message'       )});
       }else{
           req.flash('message', " Log in here for user profile")
           res.redirect('/login')
       }
})

Comment: Please provide that code into your question. It is very difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: sorry ,i have added sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use if-else in EJS

```
<% if(condition){ %>
    <h1>foo</h1>
<% } else{ %>  
    <h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

You are using `user` instead of `userSchema`, this could be an issue here.